# Hacklang — Is there a reason why ConstIndexAccess is invariant on Tk?

Tags: collections, contravariance, hacklang

#### Context

I'm building an application that benefits from versatile collection wrappers, so I've set my sights on the Hack collection interfaces. Two of them are particularly promising: `KeyedContainer<+Tk, +Tv>` and `ConstIndexAccess<Tk, +Tv>`. The square-bracket access syntax allows `Tk` to be covariant in the former which has proven very useful — getter methods otherwise would require `Tk` in the argument (contravariant) position. That means I can access elements in sublinear time (argument-position `Tk`), or loop over the collection and access keys (return-position `Tk`) as I wish. The downside is that `KeyedContainer` is impossible to extend usefully: it doesn't define any methods.

At the moment, I need a mutable keyed collection type with an immutable ancestor. With this restriction on `KeyedContainer`, I'm considering biting the bullet by giving up keyed `foreach` and using `ConstIndexAccess`, which defines an explicit getter and has a mutable `IndexAccess` child from which `MutableMap` and `MutableVector` inherit.

#### Issue

The invariance of `Tk` makes `ConstIndexAccess` less powerful of a type, but also suggests that maybe there is some way to read keys from them. Is this the reason that `ConstIndexAccess` isn't contravariant on `Tk`? None of its descendants are covariant on `Tk`, and it is not possible to iterate using `foreach`. All other standard Hack contracts as far as I can tell have as flexible variances as possible except this one.